# Center Inside Table Using Styled Components/CSS

Tags: css, reactjs, react-hooks, styled-components

I need to center the `"No data available"` on the table. How do I center it without touching the TableHeader css?

Codesandbox here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/table-empty-styled-components-86246?file=/src/Table/index.js)

```
const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Center = () => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <Container>No data available</Container>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `colspan="5"` to your TD to make the single col in your `tbody` match the length of the 5 cols in your `thead`.

The number in "colspan" needs to match the number of columns in your `thead`, so if that `thead` is dynamic, you need to make the number in `colspan` dynamic too.

```
const Container = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
`;

const Center = () => {
  return (
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
          <Container>No data available</Container>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  );
};
```